# Dhtmlx tree items

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

Is it possible to insert in the same node of the tree two items? I need once editable and other not editable.I made my tree with `javascript` array like code below,and I would like to have only the letter `A` editable and not the entire item,so I thought to divide the item in two item, once editable and other not but I don't know if is it possible.

```
treeArray.push([10,father, A + " " + "=(" + x +" " + y +" "+ z +")"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=39336&p=123049#p123049)  is demo code with similar approach you are searching. You can do by analogy with provided example